# Solving the non-linear equation by means of Newton-Raphson iteration in R

Tags: r, iteration, solver, nonlinear-functions, exp

I am biologist struggeling to solve the following non-linear equation:

`R^2*exp(c*R) =Ccf*Acf*E*(I/Ke+I)`

where c, Ccf, Acf,E and Ke are fixed values and I is a vector with irradiance values.

I assume that Newton-Raphson iteration would be the appropriate way but I cant get it to work with neither multiroot {rootSolve} nor with newtonraphson {spuRs}.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show what you already tried? (ie a reproducible example)

Comment: Hope that gives and idea...`library(spuRs)

  getR <- function (R) {
    
    Ccf         = c(0.3)      
    Acf         = c(3*10^-6)  
    E           = c(0.00006)  
    Ke          = c(1000)  
    I           = c(150)
    c           = c(0.1)
    
    R^2*exp(c*R) =Ccf*Acf*E*(I/Ke+I)
  }

newtonraphson(getR, 2, 1e-6)`

Comment: [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%28x^2*exp%28c*x%29%3Db%2Cx%29#) is what wolframalpha.com suggests for an equation of this type.

Comment: I am familiar with wolframalpha.com, but it hasen't clicked yet how to use that in R

Comment: For completeness the link to the solution as I finally implemented it into my model

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167058/use-values-from-different-dataframes-as-input-for-nested-function/32167555#32167555