# use values from different dataframes as input for nested function

Tags: r, function, wrapper

How do I run the following piece of code that the output of function `ftn4` using values from data frame `I`, is used by the `newtonraphson` function in combination with values from data frame `R0`. I would like to store the output in a new data frame (`R`) of the same dimensions (ncol = 5, nrow = 5) as `I` an `R0`.

I am stuck, any ideas? Any hint greatly appreciated

```
c           = c(0.3)      
Ccf         = c(0.3)      
Acf         = c(3*10^-6)  
E           = c(0.00006) 
Ke          = c(1000)    

I           = as.data.frame(matrix(sample(seq(150,300,0.1),25), ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
R0          = as.data.frame(matrix(sample(seq(0.01,0.2,0.001),25), ncol = 5, nrow = 5))

library(spuRs) 

ftn4 <- function(x) {
  f = { x^2*exp(c*x)- (Ccf*Acf*E*(I/Ke+I))}
  f1 = { 2 * x * exp(c * x) + x^2 * (exp(c * x) * c)}
        return(c(f,f1))
}

R = as.data.frame(newtonraphson(ftn4, R0, tol = 1e-09 ,max.iter = 1000))
```

Comment: Your function is trying to create a vector c(f,f1), by using a dataframe f and a value f1. Try using an example like ftn4(0.012). Looks like you have to update your function and then apply it on every column of R0.

Comment: @AntoniosK the problem is that the `newtonraphson` function needs as an input a function that yields a vector like `c(f,f1)`, because it uses iteration processes to converge both values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As appointed by the comments, you should pass arguments to the function ftn4 that yields to a value.  So ftn4, should be changed by:

```
ftn4 <- function(x,I) {
  f = { x^2*exp(c*x)- (Ccf*Acf*E*(I/Ke+I))}
  f1 = { 2 * x * exp(c * x) + x^2 * (exp(c * x) * c)}
  return(c(f,f1))
}
```

And now iterate over your matrix I and R0.

```
R <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=nrow(I), ncol(I)))
for(i in 1:nrow(I)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(I)){
    R[i,j] <- newtonraphson(ftn  = function(x) ftn4(x, I[i,j]), 
                            x0  = R0[i,j], 
                            tol = 1e-09, 
                            max.iter = 1000)
  }
}
```

Comment: @Vincent if I run your code i receive the following error message:`Error in newtonraphson(fx = function(x) ftn4(x, I[i, j]), x0 = R0[i, j],  : 
  unused argument (fx = function(x) ftn4(x, I[i, j]))`

Comment: Yeah sorry, the input must be called ftn, not fx! Now it's working for me, but i don't know if it's your desired result